# ng-click function immediately executing function without clicking

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and trying to setup a login system. I have some 'buttons' setup to redirect users to an Oauth prompt to users facebook/google account when the button is clicked. My problem is that the function to log users in is executing immediately on page log and not when the button is clicked.

I am pretty sure the root lies in the way JS objects work but I am still learning angularjs and it is a bit confusing.

I believe that putting the functions on the $scope will execute them immediately but I don't see how else I can expose them to the ng-click.

Could someone help me work out how to make the buttons work as expected?

template:

```
<ion-view title="Account">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content class="has-header padding">

        <h1 ng-click="google_login()">Log in with Google</h1>
        <h1 ng-click="fb_login()">Log in with Facebook</h1>
        <h1 ng-click="dev_login()">Dev login</h1>
        <div id="logs"></div>
        <form class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" required>
            </label>
            <div class="padding">
                <button class="button button-block button-stable" ng-click="email_authenticate()">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller:

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $state, Authentication) {
    $scope.dev_login = Authentication.dev_authenticate(); //executes immediately
    $scope.fb_login = Authentication.fb_authenticate(); //executes immediately
    $scope.google_login = Authentication.google_authenticate(); //executes immediately
    $scope.email_login = Authentication.email_authenticate(); //executes immediately
    $scope.logout = Authentication.logout();
});
```

These are defined in services.js:

```
.factory('Authentication', function ($http) {
    return {
        authenticate: function () {
            return $http({
                url: 'https://api.squawkfinace.com/authenticate',
                method: 'post'//,
                //data: {facebook_authtoken: key}
            });
        },
        fb_authenticate: function () {
            return $.oauth2({
                 //Oauth details
            }, function (token, response) {
                localStorage.setItem("LoggedInAccount", JSON.stringify({'platform': 'facebook', 'token': token}));
                console.log(token);
                $state.transitionTo("app.notifications");
            }, function (error, response) {
                // do something with error object
            });
        },
        google_authenticate: function () {
            return $.oauth2({
                //oauth details
            }, function (token, response) {
                localStorage.setItem("Account", JSON.stringify({'platform': 'google', 'key': token}));

            }, function (error, response) {
                // do something with error object
                $("#logs").append("<p class='error'><b>error: </b>" + JSON.stringify(error) + "</p>");
                $("#logs").append("<p class='error'><b>response: </b>" + JSON.stringify(response) + "</p>");
            });
        },
        dev_authenticate: function () {
            return null;
        },
        email_authenticate: function () {
          return null;
        },
        logout: function () {
            localStorage.removeItem("Account");
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're actually executing the functions

```
$scope.dev_login = Authentication.dev_authenticate();
```

should be

```
$scope.dev_login = Authentication.dev_authenticate;
```

The first scenario executes the function and assigns the result to $scope. You want to assign the reference to the function instead.